# Cancel notification

Tags: android, notifications, onesignal

I use Onesignal to push notification and need to cancel all   notification  of onPause and onResume,

```java
 NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        if (notificationManager!=null)
            notificationManager.cancelAll();
```

but it's not work correctly. When app restarted I get all old notifications.  I restard my app and these old notifications need to not showing.
Please help to fix this!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use this method from OneSignal SDK `clearOneSignalNotifications`

or for only one notifcation `cancelNotification`.

[Check here](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/android-native-sdk#section--cancelnotification-)